# Cassandra 2.1.17: sstableloader miss tombstone with -cph3

Tags: cassandra

While using Cassandra 2.1.17, I encounter a problem in this scenario:

1. backup and upload data to aws s3 from the production environment (3-nodes cluster)
2. download these data local
3. restore these data to the local cassandra (single-node) with this command:
   /$cassandra_path/bin/sstableloader -d $local_ip -cph 3 $sstable_path
4. do some calculation with the local data

Sometimes I can get lot of extra data in local cassandra cluster which can not be found in the online cluster.

I pick one of these records, using the sstable2json to explain the sstables, I can find a tombstone record with the exactly key in the file where I download from s3 directly, whose timestamp is greater than the record's. That means this record has been deleted and for some reason, it revived during restore to the local cluster.

What's more, I search the local cluster's data, only the data record is still here while I can't find the tombstone record.

Have anyone met this before? Is't a sstableloader's bug? If so, how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering about how well time might be synchronized between prod cluster and local node and if this could influence on TS revival...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should add some more details there. 1) Actually, I have three  online clusters and a ntp server is used to synchronize their time. And each time, it will happened in only one cluster.  2) When this happened, it affects more than 1/3 records (280,000 in 630,000). 3) The timestamp of the record is in 2017.02 however it was delete in 2017.10. Above all, I think it might not be the synchronized between prod cluster and local node.

Comment: Deleted in 2017.10 then it ought to be electable for physical removal by compaction I would think.  Are CFs never compacted and TS removed?

Comment: It seems that the system.compaction_history only keeps about 3 weeks compaction log, I do not know exactly whether it compacted since 2017.10. However, since the TS still there, there must be no compaction on this column family from then on. Thanks for your reply, may be a manual compaction on this column family is a good idea, and I will have a try soon. But I still wonder why the TS lost during sstableloader...